# Relative velocity of light in a medium

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

The speed of light in a medium is independent of motion of source relative to medium but it depends on the motion of observer relative to the medium.

I don't understand why it is so.

Comment: the speed of light is constant but the distance traveled changes as it bounces around between atoms in the medium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speed of light with respect to an observer in a medium depends on its refractive index only, and therefore has no reason to change if the source is moving or stationary (although the refractive index depends on wavelength of light, which can in turn change the speed of light in the medium, we ignore this aspect entirely). However if the observer is is moving, then in order to find the speed of light with respect to the observer, you need to apply velocity addition, which is an outcome of Lorentz transformations and is given by

$$\dfrac{v_0 + v_m}{1 + \frac{v_0v_m}{c^2}}$$

where $v_0$ is the velocity of the observer and the $v_m$ is the velocity of light in that medium. Care should be taken that this is not the same velocity addition as in case of non-relativistic mechanics, but simplifies to that in appropriate limits. So the speed of light with respect to the observer changes if the observer himself is moving.